# Using stop words to ignore articles in sort

Tags: solr

I having issues sorting data because of the articles such as "the" or "a".
So, I wanted to use the stop word list to remove the articles and sort by all the words after that.  However, it's not working at all.  Now the sorting is all over the place.  It doesn't seem to be sorting by first word after the article.

**Here is a snippet of the schema file.**

```xml
<field name="shareholder_nm_sort" type="sorted_text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<fieldType name="sorted_text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="sortstopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**Here is the stop words file I'm calling**

```sh
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

the
a
```

Answer (score 2):

Stopwords work on tokens, meaning that depending on how your text is tokenized, it will skip tokens that match words in the list of stopwords. The problem is that tokenized strings aren't useful for sorting, as it will appear mostly random - as there is no usable way of sorting when a single string has been broken into a group of tokens.

There are however options:

Use a [MappingCharFilterFactory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CharFilterFactories#CharFilterFactories-solr.MappingCharFilterFactory) with a list of `"stopword" => ""`. This will filter the string *before* it's tokenized. Use a KeywordTokenizer to avoid tokenizing the string further after the mapping has taken place (the string will be indexed as a single token). You may also apply a lowercase filter if you'd like to make the sort case insensitive. If you still want the text to be searchable or display the actual indexed value, use a `copyField` directive to move the field content into separate fields - one for sorting and one for searching or displaying.

Another possible solution is to perform the stopword removal before indexing in your own code - that way the words will never enter Solr at all, and you can sort on a regular StrField instead.

Comment: Thanks for you advice, it put me on the right path.  I ended up using `PatternReplaceFilterFactory` to remove the articles from the beginning of the token.